# unable to access public_html/images from public_html/subdomainname

Tags: javascript, php, html

i m not able to access images present inside public_html/images/packages/72/all_images from public_html/subdomain_name/testing.php

tried with "../", "//", "http://websitename/images/packages/72/all_images" and much more

```
$images = glob("../images/packages/72//*");
echo "<img src = "'.$images[0].'" >"
```

needed to retrieve the image 
src = "public_html/images/packages/72/image_name"
but it displays  src=(unknown)

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect and should be throwing a syntax error. `"<img src = "` is one string, `'.$images[0].'` is a second string, and `" >"` is a third string, all with no concatenation. Unclear if that's a typo here or your real code. Do you get error messages, or fatal error notice/500 page?

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$images[0].'" >; it was a typo

Comment: Edit the question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57512379/edit

Answer (score 0):

At first check your image directory

`$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
 echo $dir;//where you want to find your images`

If your directory is correct then,

```
$images = glob($dir . '/*');
...
```

Comment: yes i did. but the result is same. I need to know how to access public_html/images from public_html/subdomain

Comment: Oh you want to access main domain images from a subdomain. Actually subdomain is fully different domain, and public_html is the php web root. So you can't do that way, you must have to write php codes on your main domain and get data from there. I think you understood.

Comment: hello Paul, I need the same images to be used in multiple sub domains. so what else can be done.

Comment: Yes, if you want to show images on multiple subdomain you can get list from main domain, other wise you can get list and copy images from main server to your subdomain by copy($file, $newfile);

Comment: i have more than 600 images

Comment: not about the quantity ! millions of image will work same way

Comment: how do i do that. Please do share a link.

Comment: or can i use another domain to save all the images and forbid it to be public and access the images from there?

Comment: Yes, That also can be